# How can we hide the CiviCRM System Status page?

Tags: drupal, 4.7, status

How do I hide CiviCRM System Status page (in CiviCRM) and Status Error pop-up messages from non-admin users? I am Using Drupal 7 with CiviCRM 4.7.

Comment: I agree - this would definitely be good to know. I get people freaking out because there is an update available. Yes, I know there is. And I'm testing it out on a duplicate site so that I can make sure that everything goes well before I update your live site. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by removing the permission 'CiviCRM: administer CiviCRM' from these users.  You called them non-admin so they shouldn't need this menu?  If they don't have this permission they won't get the messages.

Comment: I need to be able to distinguish between IT admin and office admin. These are office admins but not IT admins.

Comment: In my experience regular users don't and shouldn't have this menu  so I consider it best they don't have it - then they don't see these messages.  Very small organisations (1-3 people) probably do need it.

Answer (score 0):

You should post what CMS you are using.
For WordPress, I use a dashboard plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/abd-dashboard-widget-manager/  You can set which widgets users see based on user role.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @YossiCrm is asking how to hide the CiviCRM nag dialog that pops up on CiviCRM admin pages. This is not the same as the WordPress Dashboard.

Comment: @ChristianWach is right. I edited my question to clarify